# Polymorphic parent derived type

Tags: oop, fortran, derived-types, type-bounds

I am trying to set up a Fortran OOP code where a parent type `geom` has an allocatable field `shape`. This field is allocated with one of the extended types of `geom` which are a `circle` or a `rectangle` types. In another module I have a `body` type that contains a `geom` field among others.

So basically I want to have a `geom` type which can actually access different types (then will access different fields depending on the type) and a `body` type which is initialized with the geometry.

Find the code below. This is the module for the geometry:

```
module geomMod

  implicit none

  type :: geom
    class(*),allocatable  :: shape
  contains
    procedure,private     :: set_geom
    generic               :: assignment(=) => set_geom
  end type geom

  type,extends(geom) :: circle
    integer :: id=1
    real    :: centre(2)
    real    :: radius
  end type circle

  type,extends(geom) :: rectangle
    integer :: id=2
    real    :: centre(2)
    real    :: length(2)
  end type rectangle

contains

  subroutine set_geom(a,b)
    implicit none
    class(geom),intent(inout) :: a
    class(*),intent(in)    :: b

    allocate(a%shape,source=b)
  end subroutine set_geom

end module geomMod
```

This is the module for the body:

```
module bodyMod
  use geomMod
  implicit none

  type :: body
    class(geom),allocatable :: geom1
    real,allocatable        :: x(:,:)           
    integer                 :: M=50            
    real                    :: eps=0.1         
  contains
    procedure :: init
  end type body

contains

  subroutine init(a,geom1,M,eps)
    implicit none

    class(body),intent(inout)   :: a
    class(geom),intent(in)      :: geom1
    integer,intent(in),optional :: M
    real,intent(in),optional    :: eps

    allocate(a%geom1,source=geom1)

    if(present(M)) a%M = M
    if(present(eps)) a%eps = eps
    if(.not.allocated(a%x)) allocate(a%x(a%M,2))
  end subroutine init

end module bodyMod
```

And this is how I initialize them from the main file:

```
  use bodyMod
  implicit none

  integer,parameter :: M = 500
  real,parameter    :: eps = 5

  type(body) :: b
  type(geom) :: geom1

  geom1 = circle(centre=(/1,1/),radius=0.5)

  call b%init(geom1=geom1,M=M,eps=eps)
```

However I am getting this error compiling with gfortran 4.8.4.

```
  geom1 = circle(centre=(/1,1/),radius=0.5)
          1
Error: No initializer for component 'shape' given in the structure constructor at (1)!
```

Comment: gfortran 4.8.4. With that tag I just mean that I am coding with the F2003 OOP style instead of F90. But I have remove it since it can be confusing.

Comment: I've answered based on resolving the error message, but I'm not entirely sure I follow your intended design.  Having an extending type have an inherited component which you intend to allocate with dynamic type of the extending type itself confuses me.  I didn't follow your previous question on this topic closely, though, so I'm possibly missing something.  All that is saying is I intended to answer the question about the error, rather than comment on the design aspect.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to change "geom" to be an empty base class and simply do as "call b% init( circle( centre=[1.0,1.0], radius=0.5 ) ), M=M, eps=eps )" ? (because "body" already has "class(geom), allocatable", which seems sufficient to hold the geometry info.)

Comment: Yeap. I thought of having `geom` as an empty class as well. But I want `geom` to hold a `circle` and then use `geom` to initialize `body`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have checked that twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure constructor `circle` is referenced with values for just two components specified

```
geom1 = circle(centre=(/1,1/),radius=0.5)
```

and your compiler doesn't like that.

The type `circle` has four components, `shape`, `id`, `centre` and `radius`.  In a reference to a structure constructor it isn't always necessary to give values for all components and there are two cases here applicable.

The first case is where a component has default initialization.  You are quite entitled, as you do, to omit the value for the component `id`.

The second case is for an allocatable component.  This is where things become problematic: the rules changed between the Fortran 2003 and Fortran 2008 standards.

Under Fortran 2008 it is allowed to omit the value corresponding to an allocatable component.  In Fortran 2003 it isn't.

Your compiler error suggests that it follows the rules of Fortran 2003 in  this regard and it requires a value for the allocatable component `shape`.  gfortran is [such a compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status).

To provide such a value, leaving the component unallocated, one can have

```
geom1 = circle(shape=NULL(),centre=(/1,1/),radius=0.5)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I didn't know that and it is helpful. Also I have seen that I can actually declare `shape` as a pointer `class(*),pointer :: shape=>null()` so I can initialize it. However, I have tried to access to `radius` and I cannot manage to do that: `print*,b%geom1%radius` I get that `radius` is not a member of the `geom` structure. It is not obviously, but I expected I could access this way since I have allocated `shape` in `allocate(a%shape,source=b)` now is pointing to a the `circle` type which contains `radius`. How could I do that? Thanks again.

Comment: With a pointer component, indeed, one can have default state of the pointer as unassociated.  However, I'd be wary to prefer a pointer component over an allocatable component just to get that one advantage.

Comment: And how could I access `radius` then?

Comment: For your other comment part, I don't see a call to `set_geom` and no call by defined assignment.  Are you thinking that there is such a call in the example you give?  [If a more detailed answer is required it may be more appropriate to ask a new question (after the usual research, etc.) with the extra detail there.]

Comment: A call to `set_geom` happens at the main file by the operator `=` . It should be called in `geom1 = circle(centre=(/1,1/),radius=0.5)`. So this should make `shape` point to `circle` and initialize `circle` with the arguments of the constructor. So this is actually what I intend.

Comment: I did miss that `geom1` was not of type `circle` and so there is that defined assignment...  `b%geom1%shape%radius` is the reference you want - but you can't do that for `b%geom1%shape` of declared type `geom` (which hasn't a component `radius`).  You need to do further work (such as `select type`) to get to that desired reference.  [Search for Q&A about the difference between declared and dynamic type, perhaps.]